# Подставить поле в метод

Tags: java, javafx

Я не особо понимаю, как описать свою проблему. Но суть такова: у меня есть enum список, в котором есть цвета. Я создал массив из данных цветов, чтобы потом с помощью Random выбрать рандомный цвет. В методе getRandomLetter я хочу вывести сразу готовый цвет, но не понимаю, как подставить значение.

```
public enum Color {
        Blue,
        BlueViolet,
        CadetBlue,
        Chocolate,
        Coral,
        DodgerBlue,
        Firebrick,
        GoldenRod,
        Green,
        HotPink,
        OrangeRed,
        Red,
        SeaGreen,
        SpringGreen,
        YellowGreen
    }

    private static final Color[] COLORS = Color.values();
    private static final int SIZE = COLORS.length;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static javafx.scene.paint.Color getRandomLetter()  {
         final String myCOLOR = COLORS[RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE)].toString();

        return javafx.scene.paint.Color.(цвет, который выбрал RANDOM);
    }
```

Например, Random выбрал цвет GREEN.
Я хочу, чтобы метод вернул мне javafx.scene.paint.Color.(цвет, который выбрал Random). То есть в случае с GREEN, я хочу получить javafx.scene.paint.Color.GREEN

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода ***java.lang.Enum.valueOf()*** можно получить элемент перечисления класса javafx.scene.paint.Color по имени:

```
return javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf(цвет, который выбрал RANDOM);
```

Только константы Вашего перечисления переведите в верхний регистр, соответственно:

```
   public enum Color {
        BLUE,
        BLUEVIOLET,
        CADETBLUE,
        CHOCOLATE,
        CORAL,
        DODGERBLUE,
        FIREBRICK,
        GOLDENROD,
        GREEN,
        HOTPINK,
        ORANGERED,
        RED,
        SEAGREEN,
        SPRINGGREEN,
        YELLOWGREEN
    }

    private static final Color[] COLORS = Color.values();
    private static final int SIZE = COLORS.length;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static javafx.scene.paint.Color getRandomLetter() {
        final String myCOLOR = COLORS[RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE)].toString();

        return javafx.scene.paint.Color.valueOf(myCOLOR);
    }
```

Хотя зачем все эти перечисления когда можно сделать простой метод:

```
   private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

     public static javafx.scene.paint.Color getRandomLetter() {

            int red = RANDOM.nextInt(256);
            int green = RANDOM.nextInt(256);
            int blue = RANDOM.nextInt(256);

            return javafx.scene.paint.Color.rgb(red, green, blue);

        }
```

Comment: Я просто делаю чат с набором определенных цветов